# Undefined Phase Flow

Tags: classical-mechanics, group-theory, phase-space

This question is inspired by Arnold's book ([Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387968903)). In chapter 2 he defines the diffeomorphism $g^t$ as the mapping $g^t: \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}^2$ that propagates a point $M = (x,y=\dot{x})$ forward in time

$$
M(t) = g^t M
$$

It's intuitively clear that $g^t$ forms an Abelian group, indeed $g^0 = 1$ and $g^{t + s} = g^s g^t$, he calls this group the *phase flow*. I always believed that for any continuos potential $U(x) = -\int_{x_0}^x{\rm d}\zeta~f(\zeta)$ , the solution to the equations

$$
\dot{x} = y ~~~\mbox{and}~~~ \dot{y} = f(x)
$$

was guaranteed and, therefore, so was the existence of the *phase flow*. But then, he asks to show that for the potential

$$
U(x) = -x^4
$$

it is **not** possible to define a phase flow.

I am completely lost here. **Question** Under which conditions it is not possible to define the group $g^t$? Thanks in advance

Comment: Interesting question, especially since he implies (in his example at the bottom of the same page) that the phase flow for the "inverted pendulum" with $U(x) = -x^2$ *is* well-defined.  My only guess would be that it has something to do with the existence of a differentiable inverse near the origin, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Just wanted to draw your attention to a reply to this question, it is very interesting indeed. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, it looks like the group property terminates at the end of all times, *T*, and goes no further, in sharp contrast to the inverted quadratic potential that  @MichaelSeifert mentions, which also has monotonically increasing acceleration.

Let's start from the latter, to set a baseline for normality,
$$
H=y^2/2 -x^2.
$$
Start from the origin *x=0*, at *t=0*, and discuss systems with positive energy $E=y^2/2-x^2$; and, w.l.o.g., absorb *E* into the variables so, effectively, *E=1*, and
$$
y=\sqrt{2 (1+x^2)}.
$$

As a consequence, integrating the trivial Hamilton's equation $y=\dot{x}$
nets *t* as a function of *x*,
$$
t\sqrt{2} =\int_0^x \frac{dz}{\sqrt{1+z^2}} = \ln |x+\sqrt{1+x^2}  |~.
$$

So time goes on to infinity as *x* gets there, and vice versa. The Lie advective flow is
$$
g^t x= e^{t \sqrt{2 (1+x^2)}  ~ \partial_x}  x~,
$$
and one need not explicitly invert the above penultimate equation for *x(t)* to verify this.

What is radically different for the inverted quartic potential, is that, in fact (cf [elliptic integral of the first kind](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2Fsqrt(1%2Bx%5E4)) ), *x* reaches infinity (monotonically) at ***finite*** time *T*,
$$
T \sqrt{2}= \int_0^\infty \frac{dz}{\sqrt{1+z^4}} =4\Gamma(5/4)^2/\sqrt\pi \approx 1.85 ~.
$$
So the group stops at *T*, and there is no meaningful flow past that time.

*Edit on asymptotics* : For very large *x*, the integrand goes like $1/z^2$, hence 
$$
t\sqrt{2}=\int_0^x \frac{dz}{\sqrt{1+z^4}} \sim T\sqrt{2}-\int_x^\infty \frac{dz}{z^2}=T\sqrt 2 -1/x ~, 
$$
hence $\sqrt 2 (T-t)\sim 1/x $, that is the almost trajectory terminates/expires as 
$$
x(t) \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt 2 (T-t)}, \qquad y(t)\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt 2 (T-t)^2}.
$$

(Technically, slipping the velocity in the would-be-group element $\exp ( t \sqrt{2 (1+x^4)}  ~ \partial_x) $ to the new canonical coordinate supplanting *x* in the partial derivative collapses it to *T*, terminating the Lie advective flow, as you need an invertible canonical coordinate to run it, but never mind, that's a whole side story...)

Comment: Great answer, thanks for taking the time for writing it. Although your last remark remains a mystery, would you mind elaborating a bit on it?

Comment: Thanks, but...Ach, ach... you put me on the spot... It's a whole different question. [Briefly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator#Functions_of_a_real_variable) or [else, returning to the late 19th century and its masters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function#Lie.27s_data_transport_equation) recasting to a canonical coordinate *h(x)* reduces the group element  to a dumb translation operator, as they all are. But here $T=h(\infty)$... This is the renormalization group integrated β-fctn eqn, but, really another question, indeed a chapter, in its own right....

Comment: Thanks once again, I wasn't aware of this argument, but sure it makes a lot of sense

Comment: Might read up on p 294-5, Ch 8-6, in Hamermesh's book:  "A one-parameter continuous group is equivalent to a group of translations".